# Issue Accessing .bin Files in React Native App

Tags: react-native, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, sentiment-analysis

I'm encountering an issue with accessing .bin files in my React Native app. I followed the process of saving my TensorFlow model in .h5 format, converting it to JSON and binary files, and then moving these files to the application directory. However, while I can access the .json file, I'm unable to access the .bin file.

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");

module.exports = async () => {
  const defaultConfig = await getDefaultConfig();
  const { assetExts } = defaultConfig.resolver;

  return {
    resolver: {
      assetExts: [
        ...assetExts,
        "json", // JSON files
        "bin", // Binary files
      ],
    },
  };
};
```

Additional Notes:

I've ensured that the .bin files are correctly placed in the assets directory within my project.
I've also verified that there are no syntax errors or typos in the metro.config.js file.
Despite these efforts, I'm still unable to access the .bin files in my app.

How to resolve this issue?